# Ember 1.13 and JSON API: can't display 'included' data

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember 1.13 and JSON API compliant server (Everything is local so far, so I don't have a link to share). I have a Parent and a Child models with one-to-many relationship. When I load a Parent data I get along with it an array 'included', which has all Children associated with a parent. In Ember inspector Data tab I see that both models successfully loaded. However, in a View Tree tab, when I click on the model and then on hasMany relationship I see that length is 0.

I've been struggling in general with loading and displaying this parent-child relationships in Ember. I added afterModel hook that reloads the model, when you navigate to a page over a link. I think my frustration comes from poor understanding of how data is handled by JSONAPIAdapter when it is pulled from the server and how it is attached to a model hook. Basically, I'm not sure which data I have access to at a given point for a particular view.

Thank you

Comment: This is a known issue in Ember Data https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3380

Comment: @jonKoops Perhaps this is my issue. Can you tell me though, in case everything works as expected and I get for example articles/1, which has article data and comments in included array. How do I then access the comments? Should they be assigned to model.comments or article.comments or something else? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. If you defined the `comments` as a has many relationship on the Article model you should be able to do just that.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my project to Ember 2.0.1 and Ember-Data to 2.0 and everything magically works :)